# Why does the regex [a-zA-Z]{5} return true for non-matching string?

Tags: regex, rust

I defined a regular expression to check if the string only contains alphabetic characters and with length 5:

```
use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
  let re = Regex::new("[a-zA-Z]{5}").unwrap();
  println!("{}", re.is_match("this-shouldn't-return-true@"));
}
```

The text I use contains many illegal characters and is longer than 5 characters, so why does this return true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to put it inside `^...$` to match the whole string and not just parts:

```rust
use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let re = Regex::new("^[a-zA-Z]{5}$").unwrap();
    println!("{}", re.is_match("this-shouldn't-return-true@"));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b4fbce82ef9acdecb3342ba1b893846d).

As explained [in the docs](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/#example-find-a-date):

> Notice the use of the `^` and `$` anchors. In this crate, every expression is executed with an implicit `.*?` at the beginning and end, which allows it to match anywhere in the text. Anchors can be used to ensure that the full text matches an expression.

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern returns true because it matches any consecutive 5 alpha chars, in your case it matches both 'shouldn't' and 'return'.

Change your regex to: `^[a-zA-Z]{5}$`

```
^            start of string
[a-zA-Z]{5}  matches 5 alpha chars
$            end of string
```

This will match a string only if the string has a length of 5 chars and all of the chars from start to end fall in range a-z and A-Z.